# Existence of limiting distribution in the context of discrete-time Markov models

Tags: limits, markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

In the study of discrete-time Markov models, it is said that *if a limiting distribution $\pi$ exists, then it satisfies $\pi_j = \sum_{i = 1}^N \pi_i p_{i, j}, \ j \in S$ and $\sum_{j = 1}^N \pi_j = 1$*. Is the converse also true? That is, if $\pi_j = \sum_{i = 1}^N \pi_i p_{i, j}, \ j \in S$ and $\sum_{j = 1}^N \pi_j = 1$, then is $\pi$ a limiting distribution?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: No. Even if we clarify that the pi are non-negative, there’s no reason for a limit to exist... the chain could be periodic.

Comment: @user8675309 Thanks for the clarification.